# Is it possible to set a span start and end time in seperate requests in OpenTelemetry

Tags: azure-logic-apps, zipkin, jaeger, open-telemetry

Im trying to introduce tracing to workflows we have in azure logic apps. I was hoping to start a span as the first step in a logic app via a request to a function app that would return the traceid and spanid that could be past into further nested steps for tracing.

This works only if I end the span and submit it which leads to a trace that looks like this.
[image]

Ideally I would like to make an update to the span to change the endtime and attached other information at the end. None of the Apis I see let this happen so Im assuming its a no no and against spec. Im wondering if anyone has run into situations like this and has any ideas.

The only thing I can think of is a stateful system like a durable function that doesn't submit any of the spans until they are all complete.

Perhaps my implementation is just wrong so here is the simple function app.

```
public static class JaegerHelper
{
    [Function("JaegerHelper")]
    public static HttpResponseData Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")]
        HttpRequestData req
    )
    {
        var v = SendTrace(null, "JaegerHelper", 1.ToString());

        SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 2.ToString());
        SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 3.ToString());
        SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 4.ToString());
        var b = SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 5.ToString());
        SendTrace(b.Id, "JaegerHelper", 6.ToString());
        SendTrace(b.Id, "JaegerHelper", 7.ToString());
        SendTrace(b.Id, "JaegerHelper", 8.ToString());
        SendTrace(b.Id, "JaegerHelper", 9.ToString());
        SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 10.ToString());
        SendTrace(v.Id, "JaegerHelper", 11.ToString());

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        return response;
    }


    private static Activity SendTrace(
        string parentId = null,
        string source = "DefaultSource",
        string activityName = "DefaultActivity"
    )
    {
        using var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
            .AddSource(source)
            .AddZipkinExporter(config =>
            {
                config.Endpoint = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10003/api/v2/spans");
            })
            .Build();

        using var activitySource = new ActivitySource(source);

        var activity = activitySource.CreateActivity(activityName, ActivityKind.Server, parentId = parentId);

        activity.Start();
        activity.Stop();

        tracerProvider.ForceFlush();

        return activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh also as a note ignore the use of the zipkin exporter I was having issue with the UDP port fowarding in my local k8s.

Comment: The opentelemetry spec seems to mandate sending span only at span end. Due to this design I'm creating my own tracing library since I obviously need to know when span starts immediately and not just when span ends.